# Adding icon using css :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm using superfish menu for the WordPress. I want to add some margin between the menu parent item and its dropdown and want to add an icon on the top of the drop down, so that it looks like following image:

[image]

The menu markup is automatically generated by the WordPress so it cannot be changed. I'm trying following CSS but it does not seem to work:

```
ul > li ul.subs{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul > li ul.subs:before{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/NL4Rq2S.png') no-repeat center bottom;  
}
```

**Problems:**

1. When I hover, the sub menu disappears
2. The arrow icon does not appear.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rk9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for the problem 2 is change the :before position to relative

The solution for the problem 1 is to make the menu height higher

```
ul > li ul.subs{
padding-top: 10px;
}

ul > li ul.subs::before{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/NL4Rq2S.png') no-repeat center bottom;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9Rk9/11/

Comment: You could instead just remove position and top from the css to achieve the same result. Also, there's a typo in the first css rule: Missing a g in padding-top

Comment: thanks Johan, but i prefer to set the position for avoid mislead situations. Edited "padding" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ul > li ul.subs {padding-top: 10px;`} instead `margin-top: 10px;`

[A fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XyXSL/).